# Error with Google Login and ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, blazor-webassembly

I have a Blazor client with a Asp.net Core Web API using a custom implementation of JWT for authentication and I'm trying to implement an external identity provider (Google OAuth).

From Blazor when a user clicks the link to auth with google, is calling the following API endpoint:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> ExternalLogin([FromBody] string provider)
{
    var redirectUrl = "/ExternalLoginCallback";
    AuthenticationProperties properties = _repository.Account.ExternalLogin(provider, redirectUrl);
    return Challenge(properties, provider);
}
```

Startup.cs

```cs
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration.GetSection(AppSettings.JWTSettings));
            services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration.GetSection(AppSettings.EmailConfiguration));
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                    builder => builder
                    .AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader());
            });
            services.ConfigureSqliteContext(Configuration);
            services.ConfigureLoggerService();
            services.ConfigureDependencyInjection(Configuration);
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddAutoMapper();

            services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>(opt =>
            {
                opt.Password.RequiredLength = 0;
                opt.Password.RequireDigit = false;
                opt.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
                opt.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 0;
                opt.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                opt.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
                opt.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
            })
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<RepositoryContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            services.AddAuthentication()
                .AddGoogle(GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, conf =>
                {
                    var googleAuth = Configuration.GetSection("Google");
                    conf.ClientId = googleAuth["ClientId"];
                    conf.ClientSecret = googleAuth["ClientSecret"];
                    conf.SignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
                });
                
            if (Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                services.ConfigureAuthDevelopment(Configuration);
            }
            else
            {

            }

        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
            });
        }
```

Edge Dev Console error:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=******-o1gn4lob5hcknjggl10837m3ea5om5b4.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44313%2Fsignin-google&scope=openid%20profile%20email&state=CfDJ8Ok9DyPEKDNCp3gn7utujrjiLfNm4KnoB6RC-cf3g01gBFzNSAqo54K-GaMudVevgRKaJZbcT5_O9S-jCGixs0i5SPY_CUxvM-l_DDsckOP0iHQMgyncA_-Ce_8vgCuxeozNkRWOHDJWar174-TkOgulJpYTr7b82MtOkUs3FOmiqpJ42YU2Q74y9imEFsgk8lynBRzb8Qqvh7P5kMuIg85QNnpjeO6lFbvefLDXPIzzE2r0n5sYlo1vzUG2sRbtRNgfThR6TvF-LPuMGygVCRI' (redirected from 'https://localhost:44313/api/account/ExternalLogin?provider=Google') from origin 'https://localhost:44313' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
dotnet.5.0.2.js:1 GET https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=*******-o1gn4lob5hcknjggl10837m3ea5om5b4.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44313%2Fsignin-google&scope=openid%20profile%20email&state=CfDJ8Ok9DyPEKDNCp3gn7utujrjiLfNm4KnoB6RC-cf3g01gBFzNSAqo54K-GaMudVevgRKaJZbcT5_O9S-jCGixs0i5SPY_CUxvM-l_DDsckOP0iHQMgyncA_-Ce_8vgCuxeozNkRWOHDJWar174-TkOgulJpYTr7b82MtOkUs3FOmiqpJ42YU2Q74y9imEFsgk8lynBRzb8Qqvh7P5kMuIg85QNnpjeO6lFbvefLDXPIzzE2r0n5sYlo1vzUG2sRbtRNgfThR6TvF-LPuMGygVCRI net::ERR_FAILED
```

[[image: oauth config]]

Edge Dev Console network header

```
Request URL: https://localhost:44313/api/account/ExternalLogin?provider=Google
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 302 
Remote Address: [::1]:44313
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

My assumption is that Challenge() produces a redirect which is then "blocked by CORS policy" from Blazor.

What would be the simplest yet more efficient way to implement it?

Comment: can you provide the error stack trace or something?

Comment: Sure, it's the typical cors error. I have, in theory, already enabled cors in web api through the middleware, but I don't think  that is the issue in this case.

Comment: are you using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google package?

Comment: if that can you provide startup code snippet? and did you tried allow anyorigin ?

Comment: Yes that's correct.

Comment: this ExternalLogin action hitting debug point?

Comment: and did you provided your authorized redirect URL to your current project URL while setting the project with option web server in google console?

Comment: ExternalLogin is being hit, the Challenge part is the one doing a fetch & redirect

Comment: did you provided your authorized redirect URL to your current project URL while setting the project with option web server in google console?

Comment: Added an image with my google api conf.

Comment: can you add ExternalLoginCallback in authorized redirect URL instead of signin-google?

Comment: Unfortunately same result. As a side note, I can follow the google OAuth link and it opens fine.

Comment: if oauth link opens fine. You can authenticate fine too right? The problem is happening after authentication google is redirecting to your site?

Comment: If I try to open the google auth link I can authenticate but then I receive some sort of error from signin-google, which as far as I know is an endpoint used by Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google. But I have the feeling that is yet another different error